How to price a buffet or, how to price a subscription?
I've been thinking about a problem that may not be so specific lately. How do we price a buffet, or how do we price a subscription service?
In more detail, let's assume that we are a cosmetics subscription service provider, we have k products in our library, and users pay us a monthly fee to access n products. The prices of these k products may differ, ranging from very expensive to very inexpensive, and we don't know how the users will choose the products. Still, we roughly assume that the users will tend to choose the more expensive products in the available range.
Based on these, is there any model/way to decide the price of it?
Clarification: This is not really a business question; I think it's a bit similar to some of the pricing questions in Quant, so please don't make any business sense of this assumption. This is probably a very introductory question for most of the people on this forum, and please forgive me; I'm a newbie, and my knowledge isn't that great.
Very much looking forward to someone giving a more serious mathematical discussion. Thank you very much.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantitative finance as defined here.

Not an answer, more of a opinion
If you would like to price it the "quant" way, it seems what you are suggesting is a call option on $n$ products with a month to expiry (an analogy on the subscription), where $n<k$ total products in your library and the monthly fee is the premium of the call option.
The idea behind pricing an option (assume the subscribed users choose to exercise the option at the end of the month) is to create a replicating portfolio that replicates the payoff of the option.
Since only by subscribing can you access $n$ of any of the $k$ products, assume their prices under subscription is the strike price $K_i, i=1,2 ...k$. There must be a secondary market outside of the subscription with prices $S_i,i=1,2 ...k$ for the underlying assets. Therefore, the intrinsic value of the option at expiry in 1 month is given by (assuming you can only buy 1 of each $K$ product):
$$
C = \sum^n_i max(S_i-K_i,0)
$$
Therefore, a continuous-delta-hedge of the option would require a equal-weighted delta of all the underlying $n$ products that the user would buy. Since we do not know which $n$ of the $k$ products would be bought, one could compute an expected-value for delta based on the probability of the user buying a certain product.
The replicating portfolio would be the equal-weighted expected value of delta holdings of all the underlying $K$ underlying assets.

Thank you sooooo much! Yeah, ur answer finds the key of this problem; this is more like a pricing problem for the EU option(where the users can only exercise the right at a fixed time each mo). This answer helps me to clear my mind more; thank u again!

@AllonsyJia no problem, feel free to tick my opinion as the solution if you feel it answered your question.
